# No module named pymongo - Jython

Tags: java, python, mongodb, jython-2.7

I have a python script and i am executing the same through java process using Jython.

Database - **mongodb**

**Pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.python</groupId>
    <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Java Process

```
public String execute(String val) throws FileNotFoundException,
            ScriptException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        InputStream is = (InputStream) classLoader
                .getResourceAsStream("my.py");

        PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter();
        interpreter.execfile(is);

        PyObject someFunc = interpreter.get("myFunc");
        PyObject result = someFunc.__call__(new PyString(val));
        String realResult = (String) result.__tojava__(String.class);
        return realResult;
    }
```

When i run python script, **`my.py`**, i get below error

```
File "<iostream>", line 3, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pymongo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by importing the module like below :-

```
   PythonInterpreter interpreter = new PythonInterpreter(null, new PySystemState());
   PySystemState sys = interpreter.getSystemState();
   sys.path.append(new PyString("\\python_modules\\pymongo-3.3.0-cp26-none-win_amd64.whl"));
```

I have downloaded the **pymongo** module from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymongo/#downloads).
The above worked for me, this way we can import modules through jython.